# Repeat/Resubscribe to Observable with condition based on emitted item(s)

Tags: android, rx-java

I have `enum`-values that will be emitted by an `Observable`:

```
public enum BleGattOperationState {
    SUCCESSFUL,
    ERROR,
    NOT_INITIATED
}

public Observable<BleGattOperationState> readRssi() {
  return Observable.<BleGattOperationState>create(subscriber -> {
    if (someCondition()) {
        subscriber.onNext(BleGattOperationState.SUCCESSFUL);
    } else {
        subscriber.onNext(BleGattOperationState.NOT_INITIATED);
    }
  });
}
```

Is there a way to resubscribe or to repeat the observable, if the `NOT_INITIATED` value is emitted? Basically something like:

```
readRssi()
    .repeatIf(state -> state == NOT_INITIATED)
    .subscribe();
```

I know the operators `repeatWhen`, which does not allow evaluation of the emitted items and `retryWhen`, which only acts if an error is emitted.

Comment: you can flatMap and return an error Observable if NOT_INITIATED, then use the retry operator.

Comment: Seems to be a workaround for me. I thought an error should only be emitted, if something unexpected happened. But better than nothing. :)

Comment: it's not "really" a workaround if you think that NOT_INITIATED is an error. It's just a different semantic point of view

Comment: Basically I design my software to fulfill the approach from this blog post: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/ They are stating: "I want to clear up something that many RxJava beginners get wrong: onError is an extreme event that should be reserved for times when sequences cannot continue. It means that there was a problem in processing the current item such that no future processing of any items can occur." However, I can deal with throwing an error in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap` - the below does not loop infinitely waiting for the expected value. Scroll down for a solution that supports looping.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("1");
    Observable<String> o2 = Observable.just("2");

    Observable<String> o = System.currentTimeMillis() % 10 < 5 ? o1 : o2; // randomizer

    o.flatMap(s -> {
        if ("1".equals(s)) {
            return o2;
        } else {
            return Observable.just(s);
        }
    }).subscribe(next -> System.out.println(next));
}
```

With looping till we get an expected value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> o = getRandom(); // randomizer
    resolve(o).subscribe(next -> System.out.println(next));
}

static Observable<String> resolve(Observable<String> o){
    return o.flatMap(s -> {
        System.out.println("---"+s);
        if ("1".equals(s)) {
            return resolve(getRandom());
        } else {
            return Observable.just(s);
        }
    });
}


static Observable<String> getRandom(){
    Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("1");
    Observable<String> o2 = Observable.just("2");
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("getRandom: "+(t%10 < 8 ? 1 : 2));
    return t % 10 < 8 ? o1 : o2;
}
```

Comment: But this approach does not loop? Or?

Comment: Thanks for your approach. Finally I decided to emit an error and handle it with retryWhen, like @dwursteisen suggested.