# Restart observable based on its emitted values with RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an observable which I want to emit `Integer` values, but if one of the emitted values is negative, I want the observable to emit values again with 1 second delay between emissions until there's no negative values.

I found this answer [Repeat/Resubscribe to Observable with condition based on emitted item(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546087/repeat-resubscribe-to-observable-with-condition-based-on-emitted-items) and I don't really like it because it uses recursion which may slow a device down (depending on how many attempts it'd take to get the proper results).

Is there any other (proper) way of doing that? I also don't know how to set a delay to each emission except for the first one.

Here's what I have now:

```
getObservable().subscribe(valueList -> {
        for (Integer value : valueList) {
            Log.d("TAG", "value: " + value);
        }
    });

private Observable<List<Integer>> getObservable() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(random.nextInt(12) - 1);
        }
        return list;
    }).flatMap(valueList -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
            if (valueList.get(i) < 0) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Negative value = " + valueList.get(i) + ", index = " + i);
                return getObservable().delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);;
            }
        }
        return Observable.just(valueList);
    });
}
```

Comment: how to set a delay to each emission? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291245/rxjava-delay-for-each-item-of-list-emitted/41718758#41718758)

Comment: Right now, your observable returns a `List<Integer>`. I suspect that you want it to return `Observable<Integer>`. Also, do you mean you want to emit items one second apart from that point on or from the very beginning?